# Syntax Highlighting in Adobe InDesign

Tags: grep, ruby, syntax-highlighting, adobe-indesign

Is there a way to get syntax highlighting for Ruby into InDesign? I found a few examples for how this might work with GREP and HTML, but for any other language you had to define every element yourself (which of course is slower than simply defining text colours from within the application).

Comment: Removed the recommendation question as that (IMO) makes it off topic. Feel free to disagree and roll it back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a workaround thats working with most text editing tools if you use Github. If you copy/paste your code from their web view into your application it will keep the syntax highlighting. Not the most elegant solution, but a quick one that works in a lot of cases.

Comment: Doesnt' work :/

Comment: In the settings you can choose if you wan't to keep the formatting of text you "import". Make sure that feature is enabled!

Comment: It's important to realize that Indesign isn't a text editing tool. When you copy and paste from Github, only the text gets pasted. When I pasted into Word, none of the formatting gets transferred there either. You can import RTF files into InDesign, but Github doesn't export RTF files AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, go to **Edit > Preferences > Clipboard Handling**. Then in the 'Paste' pane, choose "**All Information (Index Markers, Swatches, Styles, etc)**."

[image]

[here](https://youtu.be/omBRzRTST6o) is a video showing how to change this option.